# I need to remove language code from URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two language `/ru` and `/uk`. `/uk` is the default.
I need to remove `/uk` from the URL.

For example:

```
www.example.com.ua/uk/category
```

to

```
www.example.com.ua/category
```

But any URL with `/ru` must not change. ie. `www.example.com.ua/ru/category`.

```
htaccess look like

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^init.php$ - [F,L,NC]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(favicon|apple-touch-icon-|homescreen-|firefox-icon-|coast-icon-|mstile-).*\.(png|ico)$ - [R=404,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/api/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*api/(.*)$ api.php?_d=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css|ttf|svg|eot|woff|yml|xml)$ [NC,or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} store_closed.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/(.*)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the `/uk` path segment from the start of the URL-path then you would need to do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This does assume that you have already modified all your internal links and canonical tags to remove the `/uk` path segment.

If this is intended to be permanent then change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed that everything works as intended, so as to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: when I add RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]  page /uk doesnt work -> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Do you know what can be reason of this?

Comment: What is the nature of the redirect loop? By itself, this directive would not trigger a redirect loop and there is nothing in what you have posted that would seemingly conflict with this? If you remove this directive and request a URL of the form `/<something>`, what happens? "page /uk doesnt work" - The above wouldn't actually do anything for a URL like `/uk`, unless `/uk` was a physical subdirectory on the filesystem (in which case you would see a double redirect). What is the actual URL you are requesting?